# Android/iOS Persistent Data Storage

Tags: android, ios, storage

I'm trying to understand how applications are storing data without the use of a login system. Example, an android app starts you with 500 coins and you use some of them. You have not logged in at all and you delete the 'app data' in settings and uninstall and reinstall. The app still knows you only have 450 coins left for example. The app requires internet connection so I'm assuming they are storing the info on their server. If so, how are they uniquely identifying your device? In my reading so far it seems there is no full-proof way to uniquely identify a device every time.
I'm asking because I'm going to be working on an app where I don't want to require a login but I also don't want the player to simply reinstall and get to start over. So, my question is how does everyone handle this situation to work for both iOS and android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google offers Firebase, which is used for notifications, but makes use of a unique identifier for an application instance on a device (both on iOS and Android), they could be using this.

There are some more providers that offer a similar service (for example OneSignal).

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: Thanks, I have used Firebase but hadn't considered it as a means to identify a device. I will look into it tonight because I'm not sure if it will always stay consistent per device. I really wanted to bring this up because I know a lot of app developers achieve something like described above and was hoping I could hear some best practices or what others have actually implemented.

Comment: Cool! You're welcome, i've seen the Firebase identifier being used for this usecase before in production and it seems to work pretty well!

Comment: I ended up using Firebase. Took a while to get working but I have authentication happening now. About to post another question on using Firebase realtime database...